# Regular expression simplification - too many groups

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm writing a simple text grabber for C-Style pre-processor. The input text (sample):

```
#if 1 > 0
blah
#if defined MACRO1
blah blah blah
#if !defined MACRO2
blaaaah
#if      !   defined MACRO3
blah?
```

I want to capture the text which comes after every `#if [!] defined` statement. The output that I would need from the above text is:

```
MACRO1
MACRO2
MACRO3
```

The line numbers required to be captured here are 3, 5 and 7. Note that line 7 has got spaces mixed with tabs.

I tried to create expressions which can give me this result, but none so brilliant. My expression which gives the desired result is-

`(?<=(?<=(?<=(?<=(?<=(?<=#if)[\s\t]+)!?)[\s\t]*)defined)[\s\t]+).*`

Options used are: Multiline + IgnoreCase

But I am sure this is not elegant, and concise.
Can anyone suggest better expression please?

PS - I am using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to test the expression.

Comment: This is another alternative (thanks to Wessel): `(?<=#if[\s\t]+[!]?[\s\t]*defined[\s\t]+).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work
    Given that s containes the input in your question with line breaks etc

```
foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=#if\s*!?\s*defined\s*)(?<macro_name>\w+)")) {
  Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Will find MACRO01, MACRO02 and MACRO03 as 3 captures

Comment: It does! But please help me in understanding how \s handles tabs also in your answer?!!

Comment: Glad it helped ! \s* matches any whitespace including tabs, the * means 0 to many

Comment: Thanks! Its has been years that I revised the books. :) Yes, \s handles \t as well. I forgot. Dammm! =) Thank you!

Comment: I am using plain vanilla answer: `(?<=#if\s+!?\s*defined\s+)\w+`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this regex?

```
#if[\s\t]+[!]?[\s\t]*defined[\s\t]*(.*)
```

In backreference one do you get the MACRO1/MACRO2/MACRO3.

Comment: The text that is captured contains the whole line, not the text after `defined` word.

Comment: But, gee, Wessel!! You are very close. This works: `(?<=#if[\s\t]+[!]?[\s\t]*defined[\s\t]+).*`

Comment: I dunno I tried a similar answer 2 hours back. It didn't work! Argh! I need coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Ay Nayan

I understood that you need to get the macro reference names of all the "#if defined" and "#if !defined" preprocessor directives which are inside of a generic c source code text stream...

I can suggest you that simple regex

```
^#if\s*!?\s*defined\s*(\w*).*$
```

the previous regex has one only capturing group defined (\w*), in order to get just the macro name.

the capturing group will be filled with all the macro name occurences.

*PS: the regex must be executed using multiline + ignore case options. I tested that one with the RegExr tool http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/03/regexr_free_onl.html*

Comment: The text that is captured contains the whole line, not the text after `defined` word. Hence, this would need refinement.

Comment: @Nayan: The text that matches IS the entire line. But the contents of the first and only group is text you want to extract. Do you really need a super complicated just so you don't have to do an extra call to get the value from the match group?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work,

```
^#if(?:[ \t]*!)?[ \t]*defined[ \t]*(.*?)$
```

with no multiline option?

Comment: Marcello suggested a similar answer. But it doesn't give me the exact result. Please test yourself.